# Firebase Auth - GoogleAuthProvider and FacebookAuthProvider is replacing EmailAuthProvider

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

## Steps

- Create user with createUserWithEmailAndPassword
- auth.signOut()
- User signInWithCredential using FacebookAuthProvider or GoogleAuthProvider with the same e-mail used in  createUserWithEmailAndPassword
- It`s throw FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException (But this is not happening, instead signInWithCredential is successfull and replace the provider by Facebook or Google

The documentation is below

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signInWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)

## Code

Create user

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        callBack.invoke(FirebaseAuthResult.Success)
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        val authResult = it.factoryExceptionAuthResult()
        callBack.invoke(authResult)
    }
```

signInWithCredential

```
auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential)
    .addOnSuccessListener {
       callBack.invoke(FirebaseAuthResult.Success)
    }.addOnFailureListener {
       val authResult = it.factoryExceptionAuthResult()
       callBack.invoke(authResult)
    }
```

## Libs

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0' 
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
```

Comment: can you give us the code you use in the steps ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour. When a credential type (Facebook, Google etc.) does not exists for the current email, then it will be created and create a user session. It will also override and delete other credential types like password, and if you don't want that, you can check [`Link Multiple Auth Providers to an Account`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) to see how to link and keep multiple credential providers.

The [`FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException.html) error throws when there is already an account created with an email that has the same type of provider, for example if there is an account with Google provider and try to login an other Google provider that has the same email but not the same credentials.

You should use the [`signInWithEmailAndPassword`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signInWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) when you want to use only email/password to sign-in a user.

You can also use [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)) to fetch available sing-in methods for each email.